# Prove $ \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \frac{dH^{n-1}(\Omega\cap\partial B(x,\varepsilon))}{dH^{n-1}(\partial B(x,\varepsilon))} = \frac{1}{2}.$

Tags: potential-theory, hausdorff-measure, singular-integrals

Assume $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded open set with Lipschitz boundary; let $d H^{n-1}$ be the Hausdorff measure on $\partial \Omega$.

Since $\Omega$ has Lipschitz boundary, for $d H^{n-1}$-a.e. point $x\in\partial\Omega$, there exists an outward unit normal vector $\vec{\nu}(x)$. Fix such a point $x\in \partial \Omega$.

I want to prove that
$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \frac{dH^{n-1}(\Omega\cap\partial B(x,\varepsilon))}{dH^{n-1}(\partial B(x,\varepsilon))} = \frac{1}{2}. $$

I can prove this if $\Omega$ has $C^{1,\alpha}$ boundary without much trouble, but the argument I used there fails in the Lipschitz case. The idea is that on very small scales, the intersection $  \Omega\cap\partial B(x,\varepsilon) $ looks like the top half of a sphere.

If it matters, this is essentially the last step in a theorem of Gauss in potential theory which I cannot find details for - I have looked in every book I can find to no avail and can't get it myself. I attached two pictures of this claim in books, but their proofs lack a lot of detail in my opinion.

First by Medkova [image: Medkova]
and then by Verchota[image: Verchota]

Comment: Surely this would be a step in a *modernisation* of a theorem of Gauss; I believe the concept of measure was introduced a fair bit later